# Surface Volume: output table given all in one column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, table, volume

The model iterates through a Point Feature Class to calculate different volumes. As an output I get two different styles of tables, both in one and the same iteration. One is the actual correct output table, the other consists of one column only, having all the values written one after the other separated by commas (see screenshots below). With the second table, there is no further access to the listed values possible.

It seems like a random thing to me when to get the actual table or the error one. Does anyone know about that problem?

[image: the two different output tables]

The model is used to get the possible volume of retention basins. It is iterating through intersection points of a transport input (line) and a water body input (line), then creating a raster extraction that lies on the upper stream part of the buffer polygon only. With the z_values of the intersection as plane hight the surface volume below that level is calculated for every single intersection.

A "collect values" and "merge" model follows as the next step, to have all output tables in one.
[image: surface volume - complete model]

Comment: done! i think of it being just an output error but here is the model itself.